# ¿Cómo vincular una hoja de Google Spreadsheet a una tabla en una web?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Quisiera que, al actualizar la tabla (añadir una fila, eliminar, etc.) desde Google, se actualizara la tabla de la web.

Otra duda, entiendo que más avanzada, es cómo hacer para que si una fila tiene un valor determinado en alguna columna (mostrar: si/no, por ejemplo), esa fila no se muestre en la web.

Supongo que son preguntas muy tontas, pero estoy empezando >.<

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido. No hay preguntas tontas, tontos los que no preguntan ;)

Comment: Si bien no hay preguntas tontas, este sitio tiene lineamientos para realizar preguntas. En lo que respecta a esta pregunta en términos generales, a destacar están 1. Una sóla pregunta por publicación. 2. Las buenas preguntas incluyen una breve descripción de los buscado/investigado. Ref. [ask]. En lo que respecta a la primer pregunta en términos específicos, ¿Sabías que la aplicación Hoja de Cálculo de Google puede publicar en web un archivo, hoja o rango de hoja de cálculo y esto se puede insertar en un página web?

Comment: Véase [Publicar e insertar archivos de Documentos, Hojas de Cálculo, Presentaciones y Formularios de Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=es)